# CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER option gives certificate error

Tags: php, apache, curl

Hi I have following code and corresponding logs. Please let me know if anyone can figure out certificate problem.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////php curl code//////////////////////////////////////////
    curl_setopt_array($handle, array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'C:\wamp\www\server.pem',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $credentials,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERT => 'C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\ssl.cert\server.crt',
    CURLOPT_SSLKEY => 'C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\ssl.key\server.key',
    CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD => "mypassphrase",
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH ,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => false,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,);

$response=curl_exec($handle);
    if (false ===$response ) {
    echo "Error while loading page: ". curl_error($handle). "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "success while loading page: ".curl_error($handle)."\n";
        echo $response;
    }
    $status_code=curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
//     echo "status code --> $status_code" . "\n";
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
            echo "header_size-->$header_size ","\n";
    $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
            echo "header --->$header ","\n";
    $body = substr($response, $header_size);
            echo "body---: $body ","\n";
    curl_close($handle);
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////Apache_error_log///////////////////////

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x21a1f58
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x21a1f58) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to my.site.com port 8443 (#0)
*   Trying my.site.com...
* Connected to my.site.com port 8443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\wamp\www\server.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: CN=my.site.com
*    start date: 2013-07-09 07:57:53 GMT
*    expire date: 2013-07-09 07:57:53 GMT
*    common name: my.site.com (matched)
*    issuer: CN=my.site.com
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /v2/dip/auth/login HTTP/1.1

Host: my.site.com:8443

Accept: */*

contentType:application/json

MY-API-Key:@#@$@#$SDsdfsdfdsw1212312323123

Content-Length: -1

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Expect: 100-continue



< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

< Transfer-Encoding: chunked

< Date: Tue, 24 Dec 2013 09:37:32 GMT

< Connection: close

< 

* Closing connection 0
[Mon Dec 23 14:38:08.561536 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 328:tid 560] AH00430: Parent: Child process 8080 exited successfully.
[Mon Dec 23 14:38:11.019782 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9308:tid 560] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////access.log//////////////////////////////////////
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2013:14:39:41 +0530] "GET /curltest.php HTTP/1.1" 200 359

///////////////////////////////////////sslerror.log/////////////////////////////////////
[Mon Dec 23 14:38:11.627843 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 9972:tid 456] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Mon Dec 23 14:38:11.627843 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 9972:tid 456] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for localhost:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Dec 23 14:38:11.739854 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 9972:tid 456] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Mon Dec 23 14:38:11.739854 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 9972:tid 456] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for localhost:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

If I set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to **true** then it gives me SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate

and if I set it to **false** then it gives **"HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Date: Tue, 24 Dec 2013 09:56:33 GMT Connection: close "**

Any idea would help

Answer (score 1):

1: If you are using a self signed certificate this is why you are getting an error when `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` is set to true.

`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` will check that the certificate being passed is a valid signed cert.

2:The problem you are getting when you set this to false could possibly be to do with options set in the headers.

What value are you passing into `$headers` ?

Comment: I am setting two values                                                     $headers=array('contentType:application/json','My-API-Key:@#@$@#$SDsdfsdfdsw1212312323123');  This is required to access RestFul interface or API...

Comment: If I set CURLOPT_HEADER => false then I wont get any error but then I am not able to see the response buffer. following is the response.    "success while loading page: header_size-->139 header ---> body---" I have update my curl script. Please let me know whether it is right.